# Please help noob to start monero wallet recording deposit or withdrawal events

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am currently using getMonero Wallet service to create a recorder of my account withdrawal and deposit history program. The language and the environment are not yet defined.
I would like to record the deposit to my wallet and I want to distinguish each payment by paymentID. My research on the web shows that we can use the "show_transfers" command to get a list of all past history. However, in such cases, it is difficult to call each time because there are also duplicate details of past deposit or withdrawal events. Is there a way to view or record only new deposits by date? If so, which API should I use and how can I get it in the same string as the string data type?

Q1 : how to get an event signal (like a Windows API event handler) on every deposit or withdrawal?

Q2 : how to get record on each event (deposit or withdrawal)?

Answer (score 1):

To monitor a wallets activity you can make use of the `monero-wallet-rpc` program which exposes a JSON RPC interface. Once you have this running, you'll want to call the `get_transfers` method as documented [here](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfers).

Currently there is no notification system so you will simply need to poll requests to this at a frequency that meets your requirements and check for changes since you last called the method.

Comment: I see.. I was searching for a event driven wallet activity monitor. I have to make it my own event monitor. thank you for your kindness answer!

Comment: Note that a notification mechanism is now [merged into master](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4333) so will be in next release, but nothing wrong with polling (and may be preferred anyway).